# PHP-функции и место вызова

Tags: php, html

Можно ли поменять место вызова PHP-функций в HTML-коде, например здесь:

```
<div id="rbar" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <?php categories() ?>  
</div>
```

Надо чтобы при уменьшении масштаба страницы функция `categories()` поменяла свое место вызова, сюда:

```
<div id="rslide" class="container visible-sm visible-xs">
    <span class="x glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <div class="hidden-into container">
        СЮДА
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Масштаб меняется на клиентской стороне или на серверной?

Comment: Клиентской, т.е. в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Если именно менять место вывода результата функции в зависимости от устройства(мобильное или нет) - то проверка ширины документа или проверка юзер-агента и перемещение блока js-oм в зависимости от юзер-агента "на лету", либо дублировать функцию и в каждой проверять ширину/юзер-агента.Но у вас и так там всё нормально - бутсрап перекрывает отображение своими классами.

Comment: ух ты. сами догадались, или где посмотрели?)))

Answer (score 0):

**Нет, так сделать нельзя.**

Php никак не влияет на уже загруженную страницу. Вам нужно вывести блок и туда и туда, а css скроет либо первый блок, либо второй.

Comment: Php ведь обрабатывается только на сервере... Или нет?...

Answer (score 0):

Решил так: 
html:

```
<div id="rbar" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
```

> ```
>    <div class="categorii"><?php categories() ?></div>
> ```

```
</div>
```

jquery:

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
   var w=$(window).width();
    if(w<1000){
        $(".categorii").remove().appendTo("#rslide");
    }else if(w>1000){
        $(".categorii").remove().appendTo("#rbar");  
    }   
});
```

html:

```
<div id="rslide" class="container visible-sm visible-xs">
<span class="x glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
<div class="hidden-into container">
    //сюда вставляется div с классом .categorii
</div>
```

Надеюсь понятно описал решения

Comment: `append` **перемещает** элемент, а не копирует, поэтому можно не вызывать `remove`

Comment: спс за укороченный код )